# Knockout: Scrolling to one of newly inserted elements

Tags: ajax, dom, knockout.js

So I have an asynchronous call to a controller in c# to obtain say 100 objects.
After this is done I load it into my html page and through a parameter in the link I intend to scroll to it.

So for instance: `localhost/page.aspx?scrollToId=85`

I do this as follows:

```
var selectedItem = $("tr[data-scrollToId='" + selectedItemId() + "']");
$('body').scrollTo(selectedItem );
selectedItem.fadeOut().fadeIn();
```

This works when I have static elements but because of the asynchronous call the dom is loaded way later and it doesnt scroll to it. (It does fade out and in again).

I have been looking at the `afterRender` method of knockout itself but this too didn't give any change.

Is there a way to wait for the actual dom to render all elements and only after this is done, scroll to it?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a more complete example that shows this problem? AfterRender should work for this, I think.

Comment: I'd like to see how you're getting selectedItemId(), and what your template looks like.  Could you make a jsFiddle of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was actually that afterRender only works on templates. I moved my view to a template then afterRender works.